# cypress-cucumber-preprocessor Datatables

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, e2e-testing

I saw some similar post to mine but I didn't find it helpful at all since none of them are using the cypress preprocessor.

I have a Scenario:

```
Scenario: Some scenario
   Given ...
   When ...
   Then I should see "<task_field>" field as "<field_value>"
   Examples:
      | task_field        | field_value |
      | some_field1       | some_value1 |
      | some_field2       | some_value2 |
      | some_field3       | some_value3 |
```

The .js file has:

```
Then('I should see {string} field as {string}',  (field, value ) => {
  switch (field) {
    case 'some_field1':
      cy.get('.someClass1').contains(value)
      break
    case 'some_field2':
      cy.get('.someClass2').contains(value)
      break
    case 'some_field3':
      cy.get('.someClass3').contains(value)
      break
    default:
      throw new Error(`Invalid field: ${field}`)
  }
})
```

My goal is to check each some_field if it equals to some_value, but currently cypress throws me an error and it's not even giving me the option to execute the test:

Any help would be appreciated
Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After 2 hours of debugging I find out that I have forgotten to include `Outline` world in the Scenario definition in order the test to be able to iterate through the data table.
So for future reference the fix from:

```
 Scenario: Some scenario
   Given ...
   When ...
   Then I should see "<task_field>" field as "<field_value>"
   Examples:
      | task_field        | field_value |
      | some_field1       | some_value1 |
      | some_field2       | some_value2 |
      | some_field3       | some_value3 |
```

Is to include in the first line `Outline`:

```
Scenario Outline: Some scenario
   Given ...
   When ...
   Then I should see "<task_field>" field as "<field_value>"
   Examples:
      | task_field        | field_value |
      | some_field1       | some_value1 |
      | some_field2       | some_value2 |
      | some_field3       | some_value3 |
```

I think is been a long day for me.
Hope this helps to someone with a similar issue!

Comment: FAIL. FAIL AGAIN. FAIL BETTER.